# ajax function not redirecting to other page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Hi, I have a ajax function, and I am not able to redirect to my desired controller in cakephp

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url:  "/NewEvents/some_function",
    data:array,
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
    alert('hello');
}
```

NewEvents is my controller, some_function is where I want the data to go...

```
// In my controller file
 function some_function()
 {
       some code.....
 }
```

And how to change the output format ??

Can anyone help me with my code ??

Comment: you are missing the closing bracket `});`

Comment: Damn, double check syntax errors before posting here!

Comment: Try to provide URL of your application such as `/your_app/NewEvents/some_function`. Also have a look at console panel of Firebug to see if you have got any errors in your script.

Comment: Please correct the syntax error and provide more details, as mentioned in other answers / comments.

Comment: have any CSRF protection. in your site ? may be automatically inserts the hidden token fields into the form , then check and block

Comment: What is your error exactly? The ajax call throws a 500 error? Or you receive the some_function() output but you can't handle the data in js? You want to change the output format how?

Answer (score 1):

use ajax success function after successful completion of ajax request follow the code given below,

```
$.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/NewEvents/some_function",
        data:array, //data you want to pass the
        success: function (data) {
        alert('hello'); // after success hello will alert.
        }
        });
```